# How to get all objects linked to a given foreign ket field using rest_framework serializers?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-serializer

I have two models and I want to call the field values associated with the foreign key present in both the models.
For example:
Say we have two models:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Bike(models.Model):
        bike_model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Car(models.Model):
        car_model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And the relating serializer class is:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import Bike,Car

    class BikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Bike
            fields = ('bike_model','owner')

    class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Car
            fields = ('car_model','owner')
```

Now, I want to add a field in BikeSerializer to get all the cars associated with the given owner. That is I want to make the following change:

```
    class BikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        cars_owned = ???
        class Meta:
            model = Bike
            fields = ('bike_model','owner','cars_owned')
```

I am unable to get how the cars owned by the owner can be returned. Thus, for the data from serializer, I want the bike model, the owner id and the list of all the car ids that the owner has.

Answer (score 0):

You should look this [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).
Basically, you need to create a method inside BikeSerializer that return cars owned.

```
class BikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        cars_owned = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

        class Meta:
            model = Bike
            fields = ('bike_model','owner','cars_owned')

        def get_cars_owned(self, object):
            # This is your query to get all cars associated
            return object.cars_owned.all()
```

Comment: Hi, I mean that the list of cars that the bike owner owns at that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You may add seializer as field:

```py
class BikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        cars_owned = CarSerializer(source='owner.car_set', many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Bike
            fields = ('bike_model','owner','cars_owned')
```